# MySQL find row through another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-division

I have two tables:

**game**

```
`id`        INT(11)
```

**game_tags**

```
`game`      INT(11)
`tag_id`    INT(11)
```

**game_tags.game** = **game.id**

I am horrible with MySQL, so here is my question: I want to be able to find what `games` have a certain amount of `tag_id`'s.  So if I have four `tag_id`'s (3, 5, 7, 11), I want to be able to find what games will have all four of those tags by looking through the `game_tags` table.  Here is an example of what I mean:

pseudo-MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `games`
WHERE (search through game_tags table and find which rows have the same `game` field and all of the tag_id's that I need to search for)
LIMIT 0, 15
```

I know I explained this horrible (couldn't word it like in my mind), so if you have any questions, just leave a comment.

Comment: This is relational division problem.

Comment: Check this question for more than 10 ways to achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` clauses along with Bassam's query to ensure you have found all four ids for a given game.

```
select
    game.*
from game
    join game_tags on game.id = game_tags.game
where
    tag_id in (3, 5, 7, 11)
group by
    game.id
having 
    count(distinct tag_id) = 4;
```

Note that this works because the `having` clause runs after the aggregation `count(distinct ...)` runs, whereas a `where` clause does not have this info.

Comment: unfortunately we won't do it this way, group by will complain about games.* because the columns are not in an aggregate function. it will have to be done in a sub select

Comment: only if there are additional columns in the game table.  OP stated the  game table only has 1 column: `id`.  Even so, I don't think mysql complains about this.  But, if it does, you are correct, a sub-select would be required.

Comment: Well, the game table has like 10 columns, but I only posted the one column that I thought you would need for this query.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT games.*
FROM games
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT game, COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) AS gameCnt
      FROM game_tags
      WHERE tag_id in (3, 5, 7, 11)
      GROUP BY game) t on games.id = game
WHERE gameCnt = 4
```

Comment: I dont think this is quite correct, as it will bring back entries which contain any of the four specified tags, whereas the OP asked for **I want to be able to find what games will have all four**

Comment: Thanks, but as astander said, I need to be able to find what games have **all four**

Comment: @BassamMehanni Does MySQL let you say `count(distinct *)`?  I don't have a copy handy, but sqlite complains.

Comment: @AdamWagner I removed distinct, we shouldn't need it in this query

Comment: True, if no more joins are added to the query. (and if there is a unique/primary constraint on `game_tags.game, game_tags.tag_id`)

Comment: @AdamWagner good point about a possible missing unique constraint

Comment: I have game.id as the primary key.  Do I need to make anything in the game_tags table primary/unique?

Comment: you need to add a unique constraint to your game_tags table so that game and tag_id combination is not repeated more than once

Comment: I voted your answer up, but since Adam's answer runs slightly faster, I picked his answer for the question. Anyways, thanks :D

Comment: No problem, glad I can help, I am just not sure how you gonna be able to use his without the inner join when you have more columns  on the game table but I'll leave that up to you to figure out :D

Comment: Well, the actually game table is like game.name, game.desc, game.url, etc.  Will that effect it?  Maybe I misunderstood the column discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6201/discussion-between-bassam-mehanni-and-matt)

Answer (score 0):

you can do four inner joins and add four where condition like

t1.tag_id=1 and t2.tag_id=2 and ....

this gives you what you want. but there may be better performing way

Answer (score 0):

**Yeah, this is a funny approach.** Bad query. But also can be done like this. Just for fun!

```
SELECT game, BIT_OR(pow(2,tag_id)) AS tags 
FROM game_tags 
GROUP BY game 
HAVING tags = pow(2,3) + pow(2,5) + pow(2,7) + pow(2,11);
```

Comment: And what happens if `tag_id=37011` ?